# IE 10 & 11 interpret min-width incorrectly in flexbox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10

IE 10 & IE 11 interpret a set `min-width` incorrectly when used in combination with flex box.

In the image below, both `divs` have their `flex` set to `1 1 0%;` but the first one has a `min-width` of `200px` which is actually rendered as `250px` in IE 10 & 11:

[image: Incorrect width in IE 10 & 11]

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wspwd85h/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
}

#wrapper div {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 0%;
}

#div1 {
  background: green;
  min-width: 200px;
}

#div2 {
  background: red;
}
```

I don't find any info about this on the [flexbugs pages](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs)...

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36483458/ie-11-ignores-min-width-when-using-flex-width?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `flex-basis` to `auto` aka content-size and make the divs' `width: 100%`.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jofjmwz6/

```
#wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
}

#wrapper div {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

#div1 {
  background: green;
  min-width: 200px;
}

#div2 {
  background: red;
}
```

Basically both div try to take the full width of the parent, but #div1 "wins" because of the min-width, and they won't overflow the parent since you allow them to shrink: `flex-shrink: 1` (i.e. `flex: 0 1 auto;`)

Could you please test on IE10, I only have IE11.