# "inline-flex" item does not grow with its content in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I have a simple table structure made up of divs:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").on("click", function() {
    $(".cell").outerWidth(500);
  })
})
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.row {
  min-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-color: red;
}

.cell {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">x</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">x</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">x</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button">Change width</button>
```

The rows need to be vertically stacked, each having the (unknown) height of their content and be at least as wide as the container. The container has to scroll if the content does not fit. The width of the cells will be interactively changed using JS and the rows should expand to fit the whole content. For this reason, the rows have the following style:

```
.row {
  min-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

The `flex` part is needed for the cells and is outside of the scope of this question. Being an `inline` element, the row will grow with the content in all major browsers but not in Internet Explorer 11. Check out [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3tpLwz13/1/) and click the button to change the width of the cells. The border helps to visualize the behaviour. The image below shows the expected behaviour (top) and how Internet Explorer interprets it (bottom):

[image: Behaviour in different browsers]

What kind of bug is this (couldn't figure it out from [the list of flexbugs](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs)) and how can I make it work in Internet Explorer?

Comment: Is using Flex an absolute?

Comment: I'd rather use a CSS solution. In this example, jQuery is there just because I was also trying out some other stuff. I can always calculate the total width of the `cell`s and then update the parent `row`, but I'll only use it as a last resort. That's one of the reasons why there isn't a [tag:javascript] tag on the question.

Comment: @AndreiV i don't understand that here not correctly.. https://yadi.sk/d/G2jtJsCC3EuWeb

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36483458/3597276

Answer (score 3):

In IE11 the behavior is as wanted:

> The default flex behavior of flex items has changed. In Internet
>   Explorer 10, flex items that didn't fit their containers overflowed
>   the margins of the container or clipped to the margins of the
>   container. Starting with IE11, these items now shrink to fit their
>   containers (up to the min-width value, if specified). Use the
>   flex-shrink property to change this behavior.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265027(v=vs.85).aspx

So, the following `.cell` rules should solve the issue

```
.cell {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto; /* overwrites the previous rule only in IE11 */
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution I've come up with... that doesn't use Flex at all.

**Updated:**
Simplified the CSS to handle the margins and padding better. When you click the button to make the cell grow larger, because of the fixed width of the container, there is **no margin** between the **row** and the **container**.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("button").on("click", function() {
      $(".cell").width(500);
   })
})
```

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin:0; padding:0; }
div {
   border: 1px solid black;
   /*    box-sizing: border-box; */
}

.container {
   width: 400px;
   padding: 5px;
   margin:10px;
   background: green;
   overflow: auto;
}
.container::after, .row::after {
   content: " ";
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   width: 0;
   clear:both;
}

.row {
   min-width: calc(100% - 22px);
   padding: 5px;
   margin: 5px;
   border-color: red;
   background: pink;
   float:left;
}
.container > *:last-child {
   /*    margin: 0; */
}

.cell {
   padding: 5px;
   margin:5px;
   border-right: 1px solid black;
   overflow: hidden;
   width:  calc(200px - 22px);
   background: orange;
   float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">x</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">x</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">x</div>
   </div>
</div>
<button type="button">Change width</button>
```

Comment: Your solution does change the width of the `row` but it introduces another problem: the padding on the `container` is no longer visible. The margin set on the `row` is ignored (I belie due to the `float`). A `JavaScript` solution is not really what I'm after here, as seen by the tags of the question.

Comment: See how this works for you. I added color just so I could see everything working.

Answer (score -1):

> The problem:

```
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cell {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

> The solution:

If you don't want to change this part of css, i suggest you to avoid setting width, instead of setting min-width

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").on("click", function() {
    $(".cell").css("min-width","500px");
  })
})
```